# Automatically assign member when date is added

Tags: trello, trello-organization

I'm new to Trello, but one of the features that I love is being able to see all the work assigned to me. When I sort assigned tasks by due date I get a nice view of my assigned tasks.

But, there are a lot of tasks, on my personal board for example, that don't show up, because they were not assigned to me.

Is there a way to auto-assign tasks for boards with only one member, or always prompt to assign a task to a member when a date is selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this functionality doesn't exist.

If you'd like the Trello developers to consider this feature, please email feature-ideas@trello.com - Web Applications SE is a more general forum for existing functionality of web applications, not development.

Great idea though :)